# Color Picker Button

Tags: android, colors, formatting

I am wondering how i would go about creating a button which changes colors based on the current selection of a color picker wheel. I already have the color wheel working but i am stuck on the button. An example of this is in the QuickOffice app. (An image can be seen by going to http://www.quickoffice.com/ and clicking the android tab in the photo gallery)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using the color picker dialog from API demos.

You could implement the `OnColorChangedListener` inside the activity so that it changes the color of a `ShapeDrawable`, that you'll use as drawable in an `ImageButton`.